# Unable to initialize react-select in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I am trying to re-use add form to perform edit operation, i am unable to initialize the react-select fields, all other fields is initialized correctly.
In the form component i am initializing the fields using

`this.props.initialize(resp)`

data inside `resp`

```
{
"project": {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "jiijijijijijplplpl m m m",
    "member_ids": [
        {
            "value": 6,
            "label": "jose kj"  //also tried "id":6, "name":"gjjgjgjg" and just haveing id only[6]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Select field that is not getting initialized

```
            <Col sm={4}>
          <span>Select Team members</span>
          <Field
              name="member_ids"
              label=""
                props={{
                    type: 'object'
                }}
                component={MultiSelectComponent}
                {...{
                    data: this.props.employeeList,
                    isMulti: true
                }}
                fullWidth
          />
        </Col>
```

employee list is of the form

[{"id":6, "name":"gjjgjgjg"}]

MultiSelectComponent

```
<Select
isMulti={this.props.isMulti}
name="colors"
options={this.props.data}
getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.name}
getOptionValue={(option)=>option.id}
onChange={this.handleChange}
className="basic-multi-select"
classNamePrefix="select"
/>

handleChange(event) {
  if(this.props.isMulti && event !== null){
  switch(this.props.input.name){
      case 'project_ids':
            //this.setState({project_ids:(event.map(opt => opt.id))})
            this.props.dispatch(respectiveOpeFetch({"ope":{"id":(event.map(opt => opt.id))}}))
            this.props.dispatch(change("AddInvoice","project_ids",(event.map(opt => opt.id))))
            break;
      case 'member_ids':
           //this.setState({member_ids:(event.map(opt => opt.id))})
           this.props.dispatch(change("AddProject","member_ids",(event.map(opt => opt.id))))
            break;
      default:
  }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the initialization issue by using a function to setinitialvalue

```
let menuItems = <Select
isMulti={this.props.isMulti}
isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
value={this.props.input.value?this.props.input.value:this.setInitialValues()}
name="colors"
options={this.props.data}
onBlur={() => { this.props.input.onBlur(this.props.input.value); }}
getOptionLabel={(option)=>option.name}
getOptionValue={(option)=>option.id}
onChange={this.handleChange}
className="basic-multi-select"
classNamePrefix="select"/>
```

Inside the setinitialvalue function i fetched the formvalues using redux-form getformValues and returned the corresponding fields value inside it. After this it was working fine